# Show react router v4 not found page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have two component, i want to show not found page, but the problem is, I don't want to call `NotFound` component inside `<switch>` because my switch is inside my header and sidebar.

Please see the component code.

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Header from './Header.js';
import Main from './Main.js';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component
{
    constructor(){
    super();
}

render(){
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route  path="/" component={Main} />
        </Switch>
    )
 }
}
export default App;
```

my next component Main.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Header from '../app/Header.js'
import Integration from '../app/Integration.js';
import History from '../app/History';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import List from '../config/List'
import NotFound from './NotFound';



class Main extends Component
{
constructor(){
    super();
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <div className="content">
                <History/>
                <div className="main-content">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/configuration" component={List} />
                        <Route  exact path="/configuration/show" component={Dashboard} /> 
// I don't want to put my NotFound Route Tag here, because it includes header and sidebar */
                    </Switch>
                </div>
                <Integration/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
 }
}
 export default Main
```

Comment: There has be a parent component which `declare`/instianciate your `Main`.
Use it inside a `switch` there, and  the `/` endpoint takes to `Main`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that.

**Step1**:  Created one function in Main component

```
renderWithLayout = (component) => {
    return (<div>
        <Header/>
        <div className="content">
            <History/>
            <div className="main-content">
                {component}
            </div>
            <Integration/>
        </div>
    </div>)
};
```

**Step2** : Modified the render method of Main component

```
render(){
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/configuration" render={(props) => {
                return this.renderWithLayout(<List {...props}/>) ;
            }} />
            <Route  exact path="/configuration/show" render={(props)=>{
                return this.renderWithLayout(<Dashboard {...props}/>);
            }} />
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

Anyways. Thank you for your effort :)